# preg_match(): Compilation failed: invalid range in character class at offset 20 urivalidator.php

Tags: php, laravel

```php
public function matches(Route $route, Request $request)
{
    $path = $request->path() == '/' ? '/' : '/'.$request->path();

    return preg_match($route->getCompiled()->getRegex(), rawurldecode($path));
}
```

> preg_match(): Compilation failed: escape sequence is invalid in character class at offset 20

It happened when I upgraded PHP from `7.2` to `7.4`.

Thank you in advance for you time in helping with this issue

Comment: That looks like a reference to the illuminate UriValidator.php file. This would happen if your routes file needs an update on its regular expression logic. Refer to https://github.com/Hujjat/laravStart/issues/6 If no dice there, please try to isolate the issue in your routes file to the problematic line and include that in the question.

Comment: Would be helpful to show what `$route->getCompiled()->getRegex()` contains

Comment: Hi, the contain regex value like this -> $uri = preg_replace('/{(\w+?)\?\}/i', '{$1}', $this->route->uri());